# Programmatically adding attendees to calendar event on macOS

Tags: outlook-2010, eventkit, ekeventstore

Our requirement was to add an invitee to an EKEvent.

As written in the Apple EventKit documentation it is not allowed to add meeting invitees programmatically since those properties of an EKEvent are read-only.

We tried another way to create an `.ics` file and add it the calendar programtically. But with this approach we are not able to create attendees to an event hosted in an Exchange account. Where as other accounts like GMail are working fine.

Comment: Be more specific. What exactly are you doing to add the Calendar event programatically? Are you using CalDAV to access the server? Or are you sending the event via iMIP? Exchange doesn't support CalDAV but Outlook does support iMIP. Presumably you have to use an Exchange API (EWS, ActiveSync, etc) to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. our aim was to create and send an invite and add it the the users mac calendar. For this we tried to use the Apple Event kit framework for mac as EKEvent are read-only property. But unfortunately this framework does not allow us to add invitee. We used other approach to create ics file and add it, into the mac calendar in Outlook.Attendees are included in the ics file but are not  visible in the mac calendar.

Comment: `We used other approach to create ics file and add it, into the mac calendar in Outlook` - How? Show an example of the ICS file you use.

Comment: BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:6F61522B-0A-AB95-61F422AD9A57

DTSTART:20170314T130030Z
DTEND:20170314T130030Z
DTSTAMP:20170314T130030Z
LOCATION:Meeting Room
ATTENDEE;CN=abc;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:mailto:test@gmail.com;RSVP=TRUE
ATTENDEE;CN=xyz;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:mailto:xyz@gmail.com;RSVP=TRUE
ATTENDEE;CN=testing Name;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;ROLE=REQ-ORGANIZER;CN=abc;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:mailto:abb@someExchangeAccount.com
SUMMARY:Testing ICS Filet
DESCRIPTION:Testing  ics file on MAC END:VEVENTEND:VCALENDAR

Comment: add this properly formatted to your question, also answer how you are adding this ics